# How to run Asymptote inline for TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, asymptote

I try to run latexusage.tex as can be found on [sourceforge.net](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/LaTeX-usage.html) using TeXstudio for Windows 7. I have downloaded Asymptote and put asymptote.sty in the folder I saved latexusage.tex in. However, when I press "Build & View" none of the figures are created.

When googling I found several similar issues, however, none of them used TeXstudio. The answer should probably in changing the configuration of TeXstudio. However, since I do not understand most of what happens over there, I have not figured out how to solve this yet.

I have tried to change the Meta Command "Build & View" to Asymptote PDF Chain. Then I get the following message:

> Process started: asy.exe latexusage-1.asy
>
> Cannot execute
>
> gswin32c.exe Please put in a file config.asy: import settings; gs="LOCATION"; where LOCATION specifies the location of Ghostscript. Alternatively, set the environment variable ASYMPTOTE_GS or use the command line option -gs="LOCATION". For further details, see h ttp://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Configuring.html http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Search-paths.html C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 87.10: runtime: shipout failed

Is the Meta Command change a proper solution for this? If so, how do I get TeXstudio to compile inline Asymptote code correctly?

Comment: It looks like Asymptote cannot find Ghostscript, which it requires (I think) in order to create pdf files. I'm not the right person to help with this, but those who are will probably want to know what operating system you are running.

Comment: Did you install ghostscript?

Comment: No I did not. However, I just did and it solved the problem, which made me feel both happy and very stupid at the same time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to missing installation. Solved in comments.